# How to prove : If $a_{2n},a_{2n-1},a_{7n}$ converges than $a_n$ also converges.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Could you give me some hint how to prove this statement:

If $a_{2n},a_{2n-1},a_{7n}$ converges than $a_n$ also converges.

I think, obviously wrong, that if $a_{2n}\to a$ and $a_{2n-1}\to b$ than $a_n$ converges iif a=b, because there are no more sub-sequential limits.

Thanks

Comment: You are correct that you need to show that $a=b$, and you can use $a_{7n}$ converging to prove that $a=b$.

Comment: $7$ and $2$ are relatively prime.

Comment: Could you please explain ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$y_{2n}, y_{2n+1}$ and $y_{3n}$ all converge. What can we say about the sequence $ y_n$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1250672/y-2n-y-2n1-and-y-3n-all-converge-what-can-we-say-about-the-sequence)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are real numbers $a,b,c$ such that
$(a_{2n}) \to a, (a_{2n-1}) \to b, (a_{7n}) \to c$.

Hint : Use the subsequence $(a_{14n})$ to show $a=c$.
Use the subsequence $(a_{14n+7})$ to show $b=c$.