# $y_{2n}, y_{2n+1}$ and $y_{3n}$ all converge. What can we say about the sequence $ y_n$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

My friend and I are currently debating the following question:

> Let $y_n$ be a sequence in a metric space and assume that the subsequences 
>   $y_{2n}$, $y_{2n + 1}$, and $y_{3n}$ all converge. What can we say about the sequence $y_n$?

To me it seems that all the subsequences will converge to a limit say $y$. Then any term in the original sequence will be in one of these subsequences, it follows that the entire sequence $y_n$ converges to $y$.

I let $\varepsilon > 0$. Since $y_{2n}$ converges to $y$ there exists an index $2N$ such that $d(y_{2n},y) < \varepsilon$ for $2n \geq 2N$,
and since $(y_{2n+1})$ converges to $y$ there exists $2M + 1$ such that $d(y_{2n+1}, y) < \varepsilon$ for $2n + 1 \geq 2M + 1$.

Let $m \geq \max\{2N,2M+1\}$. If  $m$ is even, since $m\geq 2N$ we have $d(y_m,y)<\varepsilon$; if $m$ is odd, since $m\geq 2M+1$ we have $d(y_m,y)<\varepsilon$. Thus $d(y_m,y)<\varepsilon$ for any $m \geq \max\{2N,2M+1\}$, and we conclude that $(y_n)$ converges to $y$.

However, my friend does not think that this is completely correct because I didn't use the $y_{3n}$ in the proof. I think he is right, that I do in fact need it, but I am unsure of how to add it in. All in all, I think that since any term in the original sequence will be in one of these subsequences, it follows that the entire sequence $(y_n)$ converges to $y$.

$2n+1$ covers all the odd terms and $2n$ converse all the even terms, so is $3n$ even needed? I would like to use it since the proof has it in the question, but I am unsure of what to do. Could someone kindly help me construct this proof in a better manner,and is my line of thinking correct? Thank you!

Comment: Without the $y_{3n}$ part, you wouldn't be able to prove that $y_{2n}$ and $y_{2n+1}$ converge to the same value - they could approach two different limits.

Comment: I see that that is true but I am not sure how to show that y_3n shows that y2n and y2n+1 all converge to y. Then, if somehow I do show this, how would i show that the sequence converges to y?

Comment: Convergence of the subsequences shows that there exists an $N$ beyond which all of the odd terms differ by no more than $\varepsilon/3$, and similarly for all of the even terms and the terms divisible by $3$. For any later terms, you should be able to get all of the differences to be less than $3(\varepsilon/3) = \varepsilon$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $L$ be the limit of $y_{2n+1}$, $M$ be the limit of $y_{2n}$, and let $N$ be the limit of $y_{3n}$.

Then $y_{6n + 3}$ is a subsequence of both $y_{2n + 1}$ and $y_{3n}$. Thus it converges and the limit of $y_{6n + 3}$ is the same as the limit of $y_{2n + 1}$ and the limit of $y_{3n}$. Hence $L = N$.

Similarly, $y_{6n}$ is a subsequence of both $y_{2n}$ and $y_{3n}$. Thus it converges and the limit of $y_{6n}$ is the same as the limit of $y_{2n}$ and the limit of $y_{3n}$. Hence $M = N$.

So you have $L = M = N$. Now that you know $L = M$, the argument you gave shows that the sequence converges. If you didn't know $L = M$, then what you call $y$ in the argument would not be well defined; it would be one value for the odd sequence and another value for the even sequence.

Comment: Wow thanks for the great answer, one last question. Do the limits L,M,N have connection to the indexes I specified before or are they completely different and I should let my indexes where I said "there exists an index 2N" be something like 2N' instead

Comment: No, I just called them $L, M,$ and $N$.. there's no relation to the $2M$ and $2N$ you wrote there. So yes you would call your index $N'$ or something to distinguish.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the fact that if a sequence converges, any subsequence converges to the same limit.  Since $\{y_{3n}\}$ converges to say $y$, then $\{y_{6n}\}$ must also converge to $y$.  But $\{y_{6n}\}$ is a subsequence of $\{y_{2n}\}$ and since that sequence converges, it must converges to $y$.  A similar argument will show that $\{y_{2n+1}\}$ will converge to $y$.

Comment: That makes sense, however I do not see why y2n+1 needs to converge to y, what subsequence is it from?

Comment: Well $\{y_{6n+3}\}$ is a a subsequence of both $\{y_{3n}\}$ and $\{y_{2n+1}\}$.

Comment: So to prove this, would it be that $\{y_{3n}\}$ is convergent so it converges to y, then $\{y_{6n}\}$ must also converge to y since all $\{y_{6n}\}$ terms will be in $\{y_{3n}\} $. Now, $\{y_{6n}\}$ is a subsequence of $\{y_{2n}\}$, and we know that this converges to y. Now, $ \{y_{3n}\} $ and $\{y_{2n+1}\} $ has $\{y_{6n+3}\} $ as a subsequence and we say that $\{y_{3n}\} $ converged to y, so $\{y_{6m+3}\} $ must converge to y, and thus $\{y_{2n+1}\} $ must converge to y. But from here how do we show that the general sequence converges to y

Comment: Do we need a formal delta - epsilon approach to properly solve this problem?

Comment: Yes, for any $\epsilon>0$ there is an $N_0,N_1$ such that $n\ge N_0$ implies $|y_{2n}-y|<\epsilon$ and $n\ge N_1$ implies $|y_{2n+1}-y|<\epsilon$.  Now take $N=\max\{N_0,N_1\}$. So now $n\ge N$ implies $|y_n-y|<\epsilon$.  This works because all numbers in $\Bbb N$ are either of the form $2n$ or $2n+1$.

Comment: So, is there a way that I can use what I had proved originally in combination of what you have told me. I'm still trying to connect the dots between what you have and what I have shown, but i'm struggling to see where they fit together

Comment: The $\epsilon$ argument you gave is essentially the same as the one I just gave. All you needed was to show that all the subsequences in question converged to the same limit.

Answer (score 0):

We have $y_{2n}\to L, y_{3n}\to M.$ Now $y_{6n}$ is a subsequence of both of these sequences. Therefore $L=M.$ We also know $y_{2n+1}$ converges to some $N.$ We must have $N=M$ because infinitely many of $\{3n\}$ are odd. So now all of these sequences converge to the same limit. In particular $y_{2n},y_{2n+1}$ converge to the same limit, and that impies $y_n$ converges

Comment: Can use this argument in combination with what I previously had, or is what I had wrong?