# Proving that if $ a_{2n}, a_{2n + 1}, a_{5n} $ are convergent, then so is $ a_n $

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I want to prove that if $ a_{2n}, a_{2n + 1}, a_{5n} $ are convergent, then so is $ a_n $, I'm not sure if this is true or false. Can you verify my proof, or give me a hint if it's false?

Let  $ a_{2n} \to L, a_{2n + 1} \to K, a_{5n} \to E $.

Assume $ L \neq M $. Therefore, $ \exists \epsilon_1 \gt 0 : \forall N, \exists n \gt N : \left|a_{2n} - M\right| \ge \epsilon_1 $. $ \exists N : \forall n \gt N : \left| a_{2n} - M \right| \lt \epsilon_1 $. $ \exists n \gt N : \left| a_{2n} - M \right| \gt \epsilon_1 $. Therefore, $ \left| a_{10n} - M \right| \ge \epsilon \rightarrow a_{5n} \not \to M $ - contradiction.

Do the same process with $ a_{2n + 1} $. Because $ a_{2n}, a_{2n + 1} $ cover $ a_n $, $ a_n \to M $.

Comment: Check this for a very similar question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/746306/42969

Comment: $a_{10n}$ is part of both $a_{2n}$ and $a_{5n}$ then it should converge to both $L$ and $E$ then $L=E$. $a_{10n+5}$ is part of both $a_{2n+1}$ and $a_{5n}$ then it should converge to both $K$ and $E$ then $K=E$. Then $L=K=E$. As $a_{2n+1}$ and $a_{2n}$ cover all values $a_{n}$ then $a_{n}$ converges to the same limit $L=K=E$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your proof is that it's unclear. First I assume $M=E$. First statement is clear. Second and third not. The statement after 'therefore' is for sure incorrect (what is $\epsilon \rightarrow a_{5n} \not \to M$?).

In my opinion it's better to use subsequences. Since $(a_{10n})_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is a subsequence of both $(a_{2n})_{n\in\Bbb N}$ and $(a_{5n})_{n\in\Bbb N}$, it's convergent to both $L$ and $E$. Therefore $L=E$. Similarly $(a_{10n+5})_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is a subsequence of both $(a_{2n+1})_{n\in\Bbb N}$ and $(a_{5n})_{n\in\Bbb N}$, it's convergent to both $K$ and $E$. Therefore $K=E$.

Answer (score 0):

The subsequence $(a_{10n})$ is a subsequence of both $(a_{2n})$ and $(a_{5n})$, so
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}a_{2n} = \lim_{n \to \infty}a_{5n}.
$$
Similarly, the subsequence $(a_{10n+5})$ is a subsequence of both $(a_{2n+1})$ and $(a_{5n})$, so
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}a_{2n+1} = \lim_{n \to \infty}a_{5n}.
$$
Therefore, both sequences $(a_{2n})$ and $(a_{2n+1})$ converge to the same limit, so $(a_n)$ is convergent